# Доустановка компонента Qt

Tags: qt, сборка, qt4

Возможна ли доустановка компонента Qt без пересборки все библиотеки с исходников?

Взять, скомпилить отдельный компонент, установить в сборку, не испортив библиотеку?

Comment: Вам необходимо подробнее описать проблему. Но если вы найдёте туже версию Qt (туже сборку) то теоретически это возможно.

Comment: @Unick исходники у меня остались, ставлю одну прогу с исходников, она требует QWebPage, а я, когда собирал Qt не думал что потребуется когда нибудь QWebKit для разработки, сфера у нас не та.

Comment: Пересборка Qt это не такая уж сложная задача. Лучше пересобрать всё с т.к. это исключит много проблем.

Comment: @Unick да я знаю, просто неохота пол рабочего дня ждать. Тем более со сборкой WebKit